# ToString("D3") is not working

Tags: c#

```
double Cost = 0.03;    
var ttt = Cost.ToString("D3");
```

and

System.FormatException: Format specifier was invalid.

Why?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#DFormatString

Says it's ok?

Comment: the page you linked clearly states that `This format is supported only for integral types.`.

Comment: @vlad you are correct...  What do you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: @Pinch in what format do you want the number to be? can you show us some examples? you can probably get what you want with a custom format.

Comment: @vlad double 4.4546 should be displayed as a string "4.455", likewise 4.4 should be displayed as a string "4.400"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Take another look at your [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#DFormatString), just a few sections higher up in the same document:

> "D" or "d"
>
> Decimal
>
> Result: Integer digits with optional negative sign.
>   **Supported by: Integral types only.**
>   Precision specifier: Minimum number of digits.
>   Default precision specifier: Minimum number of digits required.
>   More information: The Decimal("D") Format Specifier.
>
> 1234 ("D") -> 1234
>   -1234 ("D6") -> -001234

(Emphasis mine)

If you want to ensure three digits to the *left* of decimal point (this is what 'D' does) with a floating-point type value, you will need to use a [Custom Numeric Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

```
Cost.ToString("000.########");
```

But based on your comments, you really want it to the *right* of the decimal point, in which case the 'F' strings will work:

```
Cost.ToString("F3");
```

And if you're worried about the leading zero, you can do this:

```
Cost.ToString(".000");
```

Comment: It seems to me like "F3" and "0.000" are the same, are they not? What do you mean by "worried about the leading zero"?

Comment: @vlad had it backwards... should make more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

based on your comment (4.4546 should be displayed as a string "4.455"), this should work:

```
var cost = 4.4546d;
var ttt = cost.ToString("0.000");
```

Answer (score 0):

Probally 'Cost' is a floating point value. The "D" is a 'decimal' format specifier and doesn't works with floats.
Maybe what you need is in this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Links can be helpful as supplemental information, but [link-only answers are strongly discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/228805). Please include a summary of the linked information that's relevant to the question, and explain how it resolves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I will pay more attention to it.