# Nullable<decimal> ToString("D") FormatException

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I have a nullable decimal that I'm receiving in a method and validating.
First I check whether whether it has a value or not (and give an error message if it's null) then I check if the value is within bounds (basically, it's a percentage that has to be between 0 and 100, excluding 0).

So when I receive a value 0 through this function I generate an error message with the received value:

```
value?.ToString("D")
```

Except this is giving a FormatException.

I tried checking if the nullable as the problem, and various different permutations and I've gotten these results (in the watch window):

```
value?.ToString("D2") -> FormatException
value?.ToString("D") -> FormatException
value?.ToString() -> "0"
(100M).ToString("D2") -> FormatException
(100M).ToString("D") -> FormatException
(100M).ToString() -> "100"
value.Value.ToString("D2") -> FormatException
value.Value.ToString("D") -> FormatException
value.Value.ToString() -> "0"
```

It seems as if the problem is the formating string, but I have other places where I'm using `decimal.ToString("D")` to format display the values (and with 2 decimal places (`"D2"`) as well).

Is it possible that this is a configuration problem? I recently changed computers and did a clean installation of Visual Studio 2015, and I have yet to have a chance to see if this stopped working in other places.

Comment: What is the actual value of `value` when you get the exception? Was it `null`?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `N2`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22794671/302248

Comment: thanks, I couldn't actually find any questions with this problem. I just checked and in other places I'm using "C"... what a massive brainfart, dunno why I thought it was D here