# Trying to format a number so it will show as an integer between 0 and 100 but the format doesn't work?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
var a = (((double)x.Row.Points / x.Row.Viewed) * 100).ToString("D3")
```

What I want is for a to have values like "0", "1", "10" or "100" with no decimal places.

But it's giving me this stack error.  Can anyone explain why the D3 as a format string doesn't work? Note that it worked okay before when it was just ToString()

> System.FormatException: The specified format 'D2' is invalid

Comment: What do you mean by "stack error"?

Comment: I will post the error

Comment: System.FormatException: The specified format 'D3' is invalid

Comment: See [ToString("XX")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794561/tostringd3-is-not-working) please.
I wish it help you.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794561/tostringd3-is-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decimal format specifier only works with [integer types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#DFormatString):

> Supported by: Integral types only.

Also, it's used for padding with zeros on the left, which does not appear to be what you want.  For your purposes you can just cast to an int:

```
var a = ((int)(((double)x.Row.Points / x.Row.Viewed) * 100)).ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to convert a number to int:

```
int int = Convert.ToInt32(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

The format "D3" is [only supported for integral types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/formatting-numeric-results-table).

i.e.

This works:

```
int myNumber = 1;
var val = myNumber.ToString("D3");
```

This will give a `FormatException`:

```
double myNumber = 1.0;
var val = myNumber.ToString("D3");
```